# Update table based on selected dropdown value in Blazor doesn't take effect

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-8.0

I have an Blazor page where I populate a dropdown like this:

```
                @if (_data is not null)
            {
                <select class="form-control form-select" placeholder="Select a member" @onchange="MemberSelected">
                @foreach (var item in _data)
                {
                    <option value="@item.IdMember">@item.MemberName</option>
                }
                </select>
            }

@if(_selectedMember is not null)
{
    <h2>@_selectedMemberName</h2>
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Tools</th>
                <th>Data point</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @if (_memberData is not null)
            {
                @foreach (var item in _memberData)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a @onclick="() => Edit(item)"><i class="fa fa-pencil" /></a>&nbsp;
                            <a href="#" @onclick="() => Delete(item)"><i class="fa fa-trash" /></a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @item.DataValue
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

and in the @code block:

```
    public string? _selectedMember{ get; set; }
    private IEnumerable<MemberData>? _memberData = Array.Empty<SettingList>();
    private async void MemberSelected(ChangeEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Value is not null)
    {
        _selectedMember = (string)e.Value;

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://localhost:1234/api/getmemberdata/" + _selectedMember);

        var client = ClientFactory.CreateClient();
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            using var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            _memberData = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<IEnumerable<MemberData>>(responseStream);
        }

        shouldRender = true;
    }
}
```

For some reason, when I change the dropdown value, I get a blank table. If I then select another member, I get the values populated in the table of the FIRST selected member and so on.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are handling the `onchange` event of a `<select>` with the following method:

```
private async void MemberSelected(ChangeEventArgs e)
{
  ...
}
```

Inside your event handler you are making an async web request and waiting for the result. When the request completes you then update some local state and expect it to be re-rendered by Blazor.

#### The problem

The main problem here is that you have declared your event handler as an `async void` instead of an `async Task`. You have found that calling `StateHasChanged()` works, but this is only fixing the symptom and not the cause.

#### The solution

Declare your event handler as `async Task`.

#### Demo

I have created a live demo that shows this problem in action:
https://blazorfiddle.com/s/rh8l7swu

I have two `<select>` elements with their own `@onchange` event handlers. One is `async void` and the other is `async Task`.

The state changes made inside the `async Task` handler always trigger a re-render, whereas the state changes made inside the `async void` handler are only picked up at the next render (except for when adding messages - I always want those to be rendered straight away).

```
<div>
    <label>Async void (@VoidCount)</label>
    <select @onchange="@IncrementVoid">
        <option>a</option>
        <option>b</option>
        <option>c</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <label>Async task (@TaskCount)</label>
    <select @onchange="@IncrementTask">
        <option>a</option>
        <option>b</option>
        <option>c</option>
    </select>
</div>
@foreach (string message in Messages)
{
<div>
    @message
</div>
}

@code {
    private List<string> Messages {get;} = new List<string>();
    private int TaskCount {get; set;}
    private int VoidCount {get; set;}

    private async Task IncrementTask()
    {   
        AddMessage("Running IncrementTask");
        await RunFakeTask();
        AddMessage("Incrementing TaskCount");
        TaskCount++;
    }

    private async void IncrementVoid()
    {   
        AddMessage("Running IncrementVoid");
        await RunFakeTask();
        AddMessage("Incrementing VoidCount");
        VoidCount++;
    }

    private void AddMessage(string message)
    {
        Messages.Add(message);
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    private async Task RunFakeTask()
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks alot for that clear description, much appreciated. :)

Answer (score -1):

Not sure this is the correct way, but I added a:

```
StateHasChanged();
```

to the MemberSelected class and now it seems to work as it should.

Comment: In almost all instances the need to add a `StateHasChanged()` to normal UI logic is a sign you have the logic wrong:  You need to fix the problem, not the symptom.   Read Kurt's answer for the root cause.